# unable to install angular-cli in windows 10 proxy network system

Tags: angular, npm, angular5, angular7

I'am trying to install `angular-cli` in windows 10 on proxy network. Unable to install `angular-cli` in machine. Getting below both errors on cmd ( `403 Forbidden - proxy authentication is required for angular-cli and 403 Forbidden - get https://registry.npmjs.org/` ). Even I tried to add

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:portnumber
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:portnumber
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

I tried with above commands and also used authentication (system authentication) also for proxy

But still I'm facing same errors  ( `403 Forbidden - proxy authentication is required for angular-cli and 403 Forbidden - get https://registry.npmjs.org/`  ).

My password consists special character is there any issue with this.

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:portnumber
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:portnumber
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Special characters needs to in UTF-8 form. Check the symbol and replace that in you password. That will authenticate when you try to run npm behind the proxy.
example '@' is '%40'. Check the complete list.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp